# I want to know a unique idioms or phrase for this

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

> 1. That you are the man of small mind. Or
> 2. you don't seen the world you only know that thing you see in your boundary.

Don't make joke I am forgetting so I asking

Comment: Small-minded? Parochial?

Comment: I don't see much relevance between the two sentences. Can you show us the context where the idiom or phrase would be used?

Comment: There is no context.I only want to say to someone who is showing off too much..

Comment: Someone who shows off isn't necessarily small-minded. A tendency to show off can be completely independent of whether a person is smart or skilled. Are you looking for a word to describe someone who pretends to be smarter or more widely travelled than they really are?

Comment: absolutely  I want the same tell me that word

Comment: "Too big for their boots", or "full of themselves". (Note that what you're now asking is quite different to what the phrases in the original question mean.)

Comment: Another one  beside ths two

Comment: And now you tell me what I ask in original question

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want an idiom or a phrase, that describes a selfish man, who doesn't bother to even consider another person's view. If that's the case, you could use:

> **Narrow-minded**

eg: *"My ex-husband was a narrow-minded man."*

If you're talking about a person who is uncomfortable going beyond his boundaries and ways of life, you could try:

> **Conservative**

eg: *"He didn't like it when I sat with boys. He was very conservative that way."*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that a man thinks so much about himself that he doesn't see what is really important to be seen, you can use the idiom "can't see beyond the end of one's nose":

> He can't see beyond the end of his nose.

Comment: If someone's becomes too advanced and say that you don't know anything than what I say to him.Which make him fool??

Comment: Could you paraphrase the question in the comment?

Comment: Yes I am asking that I want to know an idioms/phrase for the people who show off too much.

Comment: Someone who behaves in such a manner as to make an impression, if this is what you mean, can be called ["a show-off"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/show-off).